# How do I add a TextView under each image in a gridlayout?

Tags: android, gridview

I need to display the image description under each image but I get an error that i can't cast `GridView` to `TextView`:

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/main_gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIconDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView; 
        if (convertView == null) { 
            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
          //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        textView.setText(thumbDesc[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

convertView is going to be your parent View which in this case is a GridView. That is why you are getting the cannot convert error. You are trying to cast it to ImageView (and TextView for that matter).

You should put both the ImageView and the TextView together inside of a cell.xml layout file. Then inflate and populate that xml file during your getView() call instead of making new instancesof TextView / ImageView for each cell in your grid.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) that covers these topics. He has even used your specific example (Text and Image in each cell). Once you complete this tutorial you should only have to modify it slightly to make the text go under the image if that is how you want it to appear.